# Keycloak-secured WildFly REST service returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, keycloak, wildfly-10, http-status-code-401, keycloak-services

I'm using a WildFly application server that hosts a simple Frontend-Backend combination on my local machine. The Frontend is secured through the Keycloak JS adapter and the Backend is supposted to using the Keycloak WildFly adapter.

I have the keycloak.json properly in place (in the WEB-INF folder), and my web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

    <module-name>restservice</module-name>
    <display-name>RESTful Service</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Brokerservice</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>default</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AuthInterface</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>default</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

The deployment goes smoothly and I can access, and log in to, the Frontend hosted in that deployment, but when I try to request something from my Backend, I am returned a 401 Unauthorized. The bearer token is valid and sent to the service as instructed by Keycloak's docs. Meanwhile, the console reads

```
Error when sending request to retrieve realm keys: org.keycloak.adapters.HttpClientAdapterException: IO error
```

The full server log is available [here](https://pastebin.com/kSbTYMq9). Since this issue only occrus with my local REST service (I can connect and retrieve data from other Keycloak-secured services in my company's network), I suspect that this is an issue with my WildFly configuration. Currently, it is a clean install with only the Keycloak adapter added and enabled via command line.

Any kind of help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My friends, I found the soltuion! I truly was a local configuration issue, but not in WildFly but in my Java Keystore. The corporate SSL certificate has to be added to the `cacerts` Keystore that is part of the Java distribution associated with the `JAVA_HOME` variable (in my case, jdk1.8.0_181). Specifically, you can use this command to set it up:

```
keytool -import -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias [alias] -storepass [password] -file [path/to/your/certificate]
```

Note that if "keytool" cannot be found, navigate to the JDK's bin and execute the command from there. Execution origin has no effect here.